# Heel Hook Head Kick in Karate or Taekwondo

Tags: tae-kwon-do, karate, mixed-martial-arts, terminology

Whats the name of this Kick in Karate or Taekwondo?
Chris Leben called this the "Heel Hook Head Kick". However, he does it with the right outside of the heel foot, instead of the inside.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWimUPn7_aE

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The kick demonstrated is known in karate as the [Outside Crescent kick](https://blackbeltwiki.com/outside-crescent-kick), or Soto Mikazuki Geri. The linked page mentions that this is know as Bandal Bakkat Chagi in TKD, although that may be referring to the inner version (I'm not familiar with TKD names).

This kick is supposed to use the outside blade of the foot, and when performed poorly (or in a fight situation) may turn into more of a swinging axe kick (which would use the heel) rather than a crescent kick.

Comment: bakkat would be correct for outer - 'an' for inner.